# Importing modules with new version of Plunker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, plunker

I have recently started to play with the new version of `Plunker` (using `ES6` `import` statements, so bear with me :D) and I don't seem to be capable of get a simple `AngularJS` application up and running with the `npm` module `angular-ui-bootstrap`.

I don't really understand what is `Plunker` doing under the hood to load my modules. It seems it is not capable of importing the corresponding one (`angular-ui-bootstrap`). I have followed all instructions I found on the NPM page for the package but I'm missing something because I assume I have to import this package somehow as it doesn't work. I also checked the source code for the package because I'm kind of new with `NPM` but no luck either.

Thanks in advance for your time :)

**TLDR;** How to import the `angular-ui-bootstrap` package using `import` statements in the new version of `Plunker`?

---

### ***Links***

*NPM [angular-ui-bootstrap](http://%20https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ui-bootstrap)*

*[Package source code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap)*

*[My ongoing unsuccessful Plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/SvOsgmBoSgOBDc96)*